# Display a notification when clicking on a button FLASK

Tags: python, html, css

I am looking for a mean to display a notification on the same page of my web app  when I am clicking on a button.

This not a form !!! Just a button and when i am clicking on it send display in front of my screen a message like "door are open" if click ont button open, OR "ALARM" if cliked on button alarm.

I AM TOTALY NOVICE ON FLASK !

HERE is a part of my code:

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"  >
   <title> Security </title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <h1>{{message}} </h1>
    <img class = "displayed" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    <div id='container'>
        <input type="submit" value="Alarm" id="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Ouvrir" id="submit2">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
import cv2 
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask import request, redirect, flash
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""



    return render_template('index.html', message = 'un intru est detecté')


def gen():
    """Video streaming generator function."""

    img = cv2.imread("detection.jpg")
    img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 
    frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: your question is very unclear, could you go over the phrasing please? do you mean that when a button is clicked a query should be sent to the server, because then you will need to use ajax

Comment: Have you looked at Flask Flash messages?

Comment: In fact I just want to display a message when I am clicking the button "Alarm" or "Open", I am on localhost. I just want to display a message when I am clicking on a button, that's it.

Comment: All I have found with flash message is about "form"

Comment: if its entirely client side then this is a javascript question, you may want to retag it

Comment: Nullman please can you explain me how to do that !!

Comment: there is something called push notification. Check it out. May be useful. Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML for this.

```
<div>
  <button onClick="alert('This is a message')">

   Click Me

   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my undertanding about your requirement, you just need to show message on button click. To do this, there is nothing to do in flask.

Add click events to button, add show message.
To show mesasage, 
1.simple thing is use alert().
2. If you need something colourful, use bootstrap modal
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h